# Distances between subsets of rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a matrix of the format

```
         S1       S2      id    var
  0      1.2      3.2     A1    A
  1      3.4      0.4     A2    A
  2      -2.3     1.2     A3    A
  3      0.1      -1.3    B1    B
  4      4.5      1.3     B2    B
  5      -2.3     -1.2    C1    C
```

And I want to compare the pairwise distances between all sets of `A` vs all `B`, then `A` vs `C`, and `B` vs `C` such that I get an average for `dist_AB`, `dist_AC`, and `dist_BC`. In other words:

- `dist_AB = ((A1 - B1) + (A1 - B2) + (A2 - B1) + (A2 - B2))/4`
- `dist_AC = ((A1 - C1) + (A2 - C1))/2`
- `dist_BC = ((B1 - C1) + (B2 - C2))/2`

The challenge here is to do it on subsets. To implement this I can use loops:

```
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
TESTDATA="""
S1       S2      id    var
1.2      3.2     A1    A
3.4      0.4     A2    A
-2.3     1.2     A3    A
0.1      -1.3    B1    B
4.5      1.3     B2    B
-2.3     -1.2    C1    C
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(TESTDATA), sep="\s+")

vars_set=df[['id','var']].groupby('var')['id'].agg(list)

distances=pd.DataFrame()
for v1,v2 in itertools.combinations(vars_set.keys(),2):
    print(v1+v2)
    data1=df.loc[df['var']==v1]
    data2=df.loc[df['var']==v2]
    for row1 in data1.index:
        for row2 in data2.index:
            data1_row=data1.loc[row1,]
            data2_row=data2.loc[row2,]
            dist=np.linalg.norm(
                data1_row[['S1','S2']]-data2_row[['S1','S2']]
            )
            out=pd.Series([v1+v2, data1_row['id'], data2_row['id'], dist], index=['var','id1','id2','dist'])
            distances=pd.concat([distances, out], axis=1)

distances=distances.T
distances=distances.groupby('var')['dist'].agg('mean').reset_index()
distances

### returns the mean distances
    var     dist
0   AB  3.973345
1   AC  4.647527
2   BC  4.823540
```

- My question is regarding the implementation. As I will be doing this calculation over many thousands of rows, this is very inefficient. Is there any more elegant and efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Hi @Sos, did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution without using `itertools`, but it involves a few steps. Let me know if it works with your larger dataset.

First we create a dataframe containing every combination using `df.merge()`:

```
df2 = df.merge(df, 'cross')
```

Then we need to remove some combinations (e.g. `A-A` and e.g. `A1-B1` is the same as `B1-A1`).

```
df2 = df2[df2.var_x != df2.var_y].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df2[['id_x','id_y']].values, 1)).duplicated()]
```

Now we compute the distance:

```
df2['distance'] = np.linalg.norm(df2[['S1_x', 'S2_x']] - df2[['S1_y', 'S2_y']].values, axis = 1)
```

And finally using `groupby` we can compute the mean distance between the variables:

```
df2.groupby(['var_x', 'var_y']).distance.mean()
```

I hope it speeds up your computations!